# Are Facebook Names Publicly Accesible Using Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Are the names of profiles on Facebook publicly accessible, as if I would NOT need to log into Facebook to access them?

I am intending to store a large amount of names as a small piece of a larger project. I feel as if scraping Facebook for names would be a relatively simple task using the Facebook Graph API, but I am a little confused.

I found another tutorial online at http://jilltxt.net/?p=2810 which described an easy way of finding any Facebook profile picture using one simple line:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER-ID/picture?type=large
```

This was very helpful because I am able to use a range of ID numbers and a small amount of PHP to gather large amounts of profile pictures as seen on my test page here: http://www.joshiefishbein.com/fi/photobook.php

But what I am unfamiliar with is how I go from collecting pictures to names in this one simple line. Is it possible? Is there another (better) way?

Here's the code I am working with.  The range of ID's are just an example.

```
function gen_pix($min, $max, $quantity) {
    $numbers = range($min, $max);
    shuffle($numbers);
    $x_arr = array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity);
    foreach ($x_arr as $key => $value) {
        $username = "https://graph.facebook.com/" . $value . "/";
        $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($username), true);
        echo $json["name"];
    }
}

$x = 337800042;
$y = 337800382;
$z = 1;

gen_pix($x,$y,$z);
```

I've gotten a little farther with this code, I can echo `$username` and I get the URL that I am looking for (for example `https://graph.facebook.com/337800382/`) but I do not get anything after that.  `json_decode` isn't working seemingly.

Comment: This project is a social experiment and I could easily generate names on random using other databases, but using names scraped off of Facebook would be a lot more authentic.  How could I access names off of Facebook?

Comment: Post your code, how do you get the `id`s? from db or generate the `id` randomly?

Comment: @AdamAzad added my code with the suggestion from Pete below.  I've gotten a little farther but I've encountered a new issue, what do you think?

Comment: @PeteSimmons when I `var_dump` I get `NULL`

Comment: Joshie, Pete's code should work, the problem is that you're trying numbers on random

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same way you are pulling the profile picture, you can get the basic information of a user with their ID.

[This page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/public-profile-and-friend-list/) provides a list of data that is always publicly accessible.

So you need to make a GET request to pull back the JSON, like so...

https://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/

For example https://graph.facebook.com/586207189/ pulls back my basic information. So your PHP would look like this

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/$user_id/"), true);
echo $json["name"];
```

[PHP fiddle here](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/m9k-ahh)

**Update:** Based on the code above, it's worth adding an `IF` to catch invalid Facebook IDs. Facebook IDs may not be sequential so not every one will return a name or image.

Updated code:

```
<?php
function gen_pix($min, $max, $quantity) {
    $numbers = range($min, $max);
    shuffle($numbers);
    $x_arr = array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity);
    foreach ($x_arr as $key => $value) {
        $username = "https://graph.facebook.com/" . $value . "/";
        $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($username), true);
        if (!isset($json['name'])) {
            echo "Invalid ID<br />";
        }
        else {
            echo $json["name"]. '<br />';
        } 
    }
}

$x = 337800042;
$y = 337800382;
$z = 50;

gen_pix($x,$y,$z);  
?>
```

[PHP Fiddle here](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/p7c-g64)

It's also worth noting that pulling that much data from the graph is going to take a while. Have a look at doing batch requests to speed things up a bit. [More info here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/)

Comment: this seems like it would work but it's not returning anything, I edited my post to have my code.  And your fiddle isn't working either.

Comment: Think this might be a problem with some of your Facebook IDs. Running the fiddle with your $x variable returns the name 'Jill Walker Rettberg'. However, $y and $z are not working

Comment: is there any reason why it would work in the PHP Fiddle and not in any of my browsers?  Because your Fiddle works for me now and it didn't before.  But now I am putting just the code into a file and testing it on Chrome Canary, Firefox, and Safari but they are all always "Invalid ID" even though I can confirm some are indeed valid.

Comment: What response do you get from the graph when you hit https://graph.facebook.com/{invalid-id} ?